# AC3 audio FramesPerPacket size

Tags: objective-c, ios, audioqueueservices, audioqueue

I do create the Audio Queue in following way

```
AudioQueueNewOutput(&audioFormat, audioQueueOutputCallback, (__bridge void*)self, NULL, NULL, 0, &mAudioQueue)
```

Where the format is following

```
audioFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatAC3;                
audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket = 0;
audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket = mavfContext->streams[audio_index]->codec->frame_size;
audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame = 0;
audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = mavfContext->streams[audio_index]->codec->channels;
audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 0;
```

The creation fails with kAudioFormatUnsupportedDataFormatError. 
I've checked that `mavfContext->streams[audio_index]->codec->frame_size` is 0. 
So is there any standard value for the mFramesPerPacket for ac3 media ?

Comment: I believe the answer is no (and it's only 0 if the file is variable bit rate, which AFAIK is uncommon for AC3), but the bigger question is why your format is invalid. Where is the mavfContext struct coming from, and might it be leading you astray? If you're reading the audio data directly from disk, the AudioQueue documentation recommends getting the ASBD with `AudioFileGetProperty()` (using `kAudioFilePropertyDataFormat`), which should give you all the info you need without having to hard-code anything.

Comment: The data format is constracted from ffmpeg.

Comment: `mChannelsPerFrame` is different from zero. So your suggestion is that the error is caused because of `mFramesPerPacket` being 0 ?

Answer (score 1):

The AC3 frame size should be 256 * channels, thus here I would expect:

`mFramesPerPacket = 256 * mChannelsPerFrame`.